# Reverse product list in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, reverse

How can I reverse the product list in Laravel?
Below is the code:

```
public function index() {
    $products = Product::with('owner', 'memberInfo')->paginate($this->perPage);
    return View::make('layouts.sales', array('products' => $products, 'status' => 'all'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Eloquent's [reverse()](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-reverse) function for collections.

```
public function index() {
    $products = Product::with('owner', 'memberInfo');
    $products = $products->reverse()->paginate($this->perPage);
    return View::make('layouts.sales', array('products' => $products, 'status' => 'all'));
}
```

Comment: Oops, it response :  {"response":false,"code":500,"description":{"message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::reverse()","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/website\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Query\/Builder.php","line":2113}}

Comment: I used orderBy to fix above problem. Thanks so much~

public function index() {
    $products = Product::with('owner', 'memberInfo');
    $products = $products->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->paginate($this->perPage);
    return View::make('layouts.sales', array('products' => $products, 'status' => 'all'));
}